# Alias to variadic template with no arguments

Tags: c++, templates, alias, using, variadic

I found some similar topics, but none seem to give straight answer about my particular problem.

I have a class (let's call it Foo) within some library that we are using across few modules. Now I need to transform this class to be a variadic template(so now I have: `template<class... T> Foo() {}`), as some new uses need exactly the same general mechanics, but need to accept additional parameters inside. Old implementations already in use do not need this.

So I transformed this into variadic template stored in one *.h file, but now wherever we already use this class I would need to change every occurrence of `Foo()` to `Foo<>()`, in order for existing code to work as it did.
Now, I am not sure if there are some modules that I am not even aware of that would use this library, so I thought of a flexible solution like alias to Foo<>, that would not require those other modules to be updated after this change in library.

Is it possible in this particular example to use something like: `using Foo = Foo<>`, so that all occurrences of `Foo` that already exist in the code will automatically be treated as `Foo<>` without need of any changes in source code?

Would it be possible to have such alias defined in the same file as template definition/declaration, even though it would have exactly the same name as the class itself?

Comment: In C++17 (with class template argument deduction) `Foo` can be used instead of `Foo<>` in most cases. Otherwise no, not possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: *"most cases"*. I wouldn't say that, not for members, function parameters, type (in template)... CTAD is just for instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rename the templatized definition of `Foo` to some other name `FooExtended`, then you can `typedef` the empty template to `Foo`

```
//old
class Foo;

//new
template<class... Args>
class FooExtended;

using Foo = FooExtended<>;
```

Comment: This sounds both very simple and promising... I will try it out